# Apple Pay and Ionic2+

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, applepay

Has anyone had any experience implementing Apple Pay with Ionic 2+? I see there are a few Cordova plugins out there, but these look to be relatively dated. I do not see any of these in the list of native plugins in the Ionic docs, either. I am wondering if anyone has had any success with these or perhaps pursued a different approach altogether? Any feedback would be much appreciated.

Thank you!